# Criar uma combinação aleatoria com classes CSS utilizando javascript ou jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Fala galera, queria saber se alguém sabe alguma solução de como fazer uma combinação de classes css utilizando javascript ou jquery?

O que gostaria é tendo links e cada um desses links tivessem varias classes de cor, e após selecionado algum dos links gerasse uma pagina com com um bg de uma cor e que a font fosse de outra, que seja sempre aleatória para cada pessoa que clicar, pois isso será usado como um tema para sites gerenciados que estou montando.

Comment: Cria uma array de classes e depois usa-as aleatoriamente. Mas podias/devias fazer isso no servidor acho eu. Que linguagem tens no servidor? já tens essa lista de classes?

Comment: Não tem essa lista não, isso é um projeto que gostaria de estar implementando, tenho todas as linguagens no servidor porém a preferencia seria em js ou jquery se possivel

Answer (score 3):

Você pode sortear as classes de uma array. Ou melhor, duas, uma para o BG e outra para a fonte, assim você garante algum contraste. Exemplo:

```js
var classesBg = ['fundoAzul', 'fundoVermelho', 'fundoVerde'];
var classesTexto = ['textoBranco', 'textoPreto', 'textoCinza'];
function sorteia(arr) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    return arr[rand];
}

document.getElementById('troca').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var classeBg = sorteia(classesBg);
    var classeTexto = sorteia(classesTexto);
    var elemento = document.getElementById('conteudo');
    elemento.className = classeBg + ' ' + classeTexto;
});
```

```css
.fundoAzul {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
.fundoVermelho {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
.fundoVerde {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
.textoBranco {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.textoPreto {
  color: #000000;
}
.textoCinza {
  color: #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<p id="conteudo">Texto texto texto</p>
<button type="button" id="troca">trocar</button>
```

Comment: E como eu poderia fazer para que cada um dos links gerasse uma paleta de cor diferente, tipo romantico use cores vermelhas e rosas, feliz use tons amarelos e azuis?

Comment: Crie arrays diferentes para cada paleta.

Comment: usando esse código então faz com que crie temas diversos dentro das cores que eu estipular, e que aquele bg e aquela cor da font fique fixo em cada tema por exemplo?

Comment: Isso, experimente brincar um pouco com esse código.

Comment: Vlw cara, estou atras disso faz mais uma semana e meia

Comment: Cara, a array aqui é de classes. Isso que você linkou é um script que gera um código de cor aleatório, é diferente. Se quiser usar esse script, altere as cores do elemento diretamente, em vez de trocar classes (que era o que você tinha perguntado). Por exemplo: `elemento.style.backgroundColor = randomColor()` (inclua o script antes como explicado no site deles).

Comment: Como que eu faço para que ele abra a pagina nova com a combinação, pois coloquei o blank no botão porém ele abre a pagina sem classe nenhuma.

Comment: Aí já é mais complicado, e foge da sua pergunta original. Você pode salvar num banco de dados e ler de lá, ou pode salvar na máquina da pessoa (num cookie ou localstorage). Sugiro abrir uma pergunta separada sobre isso.

Comment: Sabe se tem como eu colocar um imagem e só apareça no "tema" selecionado?
Pois eu peguei seu codigo e tripliquei ele fazendo com que tenha 3 tipos de tema

Comment: Se você colocar a imagem no CSS, como background-image, não resolve?

Comment: Então é que o que eu queria era ter uma imagem em parallax, pois como faço o parallax em puro css.
Para as imagens que não terá o parallax eu usei o bg mesmo.

Comment: Cara, isso tá indo além do escopo desta pergunta. Tente montar um exemplo simples do problema e poste como uma pergunta à parte.

Comment: Ah blz, é que como passou o código pensei que soube-se alguma maneira, mas vou montar uma pergunta com isso, vlw